# Session sharing with StateStitch and AppFabric

Tags: session, caching, appfabric, high-availability

We have an application with ASP and ASP.NET. We use StateStitch for the session sharing and stateserver setup for persisting (caching) sessions.

Now we want to implement High Availability and distributed caching, using AppFabric.

Only problem is: AppFabric requires `<sessionState mode="custom">` and StateStitch requires `<...mode="StateServer">` (tag in web.config)

Do any of you have any idea on how to go forward from here? Can't seem to implement AppFabric as //typeof(StateServer) and can't seem to make StateStitch accept custom setup.

Any thoughts, preferably utilizing one/both of the above mentioned techs... 
Looking for the free solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

A hardcoded declaration in StateStitch, validated on StateServer and failed on Custom.
Solution: Added 'Custom' to the

```
If (Mode.StateServer || Mode.Custom) { Validated = true; }
```